# How do create a class property that is a collection of another class?

Tags: c#

I have classes for Client, Project and Task.

Each Client contains multiple projects.
Each Project contains multiple Tasks.

In the database each has an ID field, and the project table has a clientid field.
Also, the Tasks table has a projectid field.

Can someone help me with the scenario so I can make each a class?

Comment: What part do you need help with?

Comment: I can create the basic collection property, but how do I make the Client class know what Projects belong to it?

Comment: If you using `EF` it will create default classes for you from tables, and you can decide how to design your DTO and improve it, the solutions provided bellow are valid, but may be your problem is not a thing we think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    // Client Properties

    private List<Project> _projects = new List<Project>();
    public List<Project> Projects { get { return _projects; } }
}

public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    // Project Properties

    private List<Task> _tasks = new List<Task>();
    public List<Task> Tasks { get { return _tasks; } }
}

public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    // Task Properties
}
```

Comment: But how do I fill the private list with the Projects/Tasks that belong and not all of them?

Comment: @Shane, that depends on what ORM are you using.

Comment: @Shane - Depending on what type of storage you are using you will need to expose methods that will allow you to filter based on properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a property of a collection type, like `List<Project>`.

However -- there is a decision to be made: Will any external class have full access to add or remove projects directly from the Projects collection property, or will external classes only be able to read the collection?

If any other class can have full access to the Project list, then you need to choose the external type that the list will be exposed as.  It might be a good idea to expose as an `IList<Project>` or an `ICollection<Project>` depending on that you want other classes to be able to do.

If other classes will *not* have free access to the list, you might want to expose it as an `IEnumerable<Project>` so that all they can do is iterate through the list.  Additionally, if no other classes have direct access, then you are going to have to add methods to the Client class to allow Projects to be added and/or removed.

By only allowing interface-based external access to the list of projects, you free yourself to change the underlying data structure to another compatible one without breaking any other code.  For example, if the property is an `IEnumerable<Project>`, you could change the internal code from a `List<Project>` to an array (`Project[]`) and no other code needs to know.